# List to datatable records

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a list with datetime i want to convert to datatable with incremented values.

Please help. I am at wits end how to go about this.

Comment: I see only a requirement, not a single line to describe what has been tried so far.

Comment: data such as `DateTime` in a table (whether in-memory on in a SQL database) doesn't actually include any concept of "format". There are rows and values, that is all.

Comment: You have one list of 6 values - it is not at all clear how this becomes a table with 2 columns and 5 rows...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks any code showing us what the user already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess by "*this format*" you meant structure of data in datatable instead of DateTime representation format. This will convert list of DateTime to DataTable containing data structured as shown in question :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("From", typeof (DateTime));
dt.Columns.Add("To", typeof(DateTime));

//first row is from list[0] to lst[1]
dt.Rows.Add(lst[0], lst[1]);
for (int i = 1; i < lst.Count-1; i++)
{
    //rows other than the first are (from lst[i] + one day) to (lst[i+1])
    dt.Rows.Add(lst[i].AddDays(1), lst[i + 1]);
}
```

I assume that your list already in ascending order, or you can use `.Sort()` if it is not ordered yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use date formating, like shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Basically you want something like

```
string output = String.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}",yourDate)
```

Put this in a loop when you want to print your dates from the list.